# array of pointers to array of pointers in C

Tags: c

I have an API which will take triple pointer as an input as below.
extern int myAPI(int ***myData);

Internally "myData" is treated as array of pointer to array of pointers.

So now in another function, i need to call this myAPI. But i am not able to build the array of pointer to array of pointers. Can you please someone help?

I tried similar to below snippet of code. But seen type mismatch compilation error.

```
int i[10];
int j[10];
int *k[10];
int *l[10];
int *(*m[])[2];
int a = 0;
for (a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    k[a] = &(i[a]);
    l[a] = &(j[a]);
}

m[0] = k;
m[1] = l;

a = myAPI(m);
```

Comment: I doubt this `int *(*m[])[2];` even compiles. It attempts to declare an array of unspecified size without an initializer.

Comment: Don't forget the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: `int myAPI(int ***myData);` expects a pointer to pointer to pointer of `int`,

Comment: Just a reminder: you got two answer. If anyone helped, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

So you want an "array 10 of pointer to array of pointer 20 to `int`" (you have to specify the dimensions for all but functions arguments where you can omit the outermost dimension only).

That would be:

```
int *(*a[10])[20];
```

For such constructs, cdecl is very helpful. The line in quotes is the  declaration for the tool.

Note this is *what you asked for*. Which is not necessarily what you really need. Often such complex constructs are a symptom of a severe design flaw. You might want to reconsider your program code.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the declaration of `m` to

```
int **m[2];
```

Comment: That's an array of pointers to pointers. OP wants an array of pointers to **array** of pointers!

Comment: @Olaf: Passing `int **m[something]`  to `myAPI(int ***myData);` would be correct. Though I agree there are no pointers to any array involved.

Comment: @alk: That because the array decays, but as asked, OP wants something different for whatever reason. As I wrote: this might not be what OP should use. A 3-(or more)star pointer is typcally an indicator of bad desing.